# Automated test system

Tags: python, console, device-driver

I am creating an automated test system (scope bloat - the original intent was a one-off bash automation of a particular test case that has turned into creating a system that will do many other things). I've done a few things similar to this, but somehow never got to using classes; everything was down at the functions level in modules I wrote for past projects.

I'm looking for a simple check/confirmation that I'm approaching this right. It's a communications module intended to connect via telnet to a remote Linux machine, then pull various I2C reads from a device that the Linux machine is connected to.

I want to make sure that I am creating this correctly correctly, and declaring objects correctly so the functions/methods in the class object will perform their individual tasks correctly. I think I'm on the right track but having people a little more experienced take a look couldn't hurt. In particular, I want to make sure I'm setting the class up for instantiation correctly, and declaring `self`/`__init__` in the right way.

Note: the code here worked reasonably well when it was separate functions not gathered under a unifying class structure, but I was mucking about with global declarations which made me nervous, and it took more tweaking than I was happy with.

```
class Communications: #logs in to the remote as root.
    def __init__(self):
        self.term = telnetlib.open('10.100.100.103')
        print ('logging in now')
        term.read_until(b"ogin: ")
        term.write('root\n')
        time.sleep(3)
        term.read_very_eager()

    #device power-up and power-down
    def node_startup(node):
        if node == 1:
            node_command = 'node_on 1\n'
        elif node == 2:
            node_command = 'node_on 2\n'
        term.write(node_command)
        print (b'powering node', node, 'on\n')

    def node_shutdown(node):
        if node == 1:
            node_command = 'node_off 1\n'
        elif node == 2:
            node_command = 'node_off 2\n'
        term.write(node_command)
        print (b'shutting node', node, ' down')

    #device sample retrieval
    def get_voltage_i2c(bus, device, datapoint, test, node):
        i2c_sample =  term.write('i2cget -y -f %d %d 0x 8b w >> /tmp/%s_%d.txt\n' %(bus, device, test, node))

    def get_current_i2c(bus, device, datapoint, test, node):
        i2c_sample =  term.write('i2cget -y -f %d %d %d %s %d w >> /tmp/%s_%d.txt\n' %(bus, device, datapoint, test, node))


    def get_power_i2c(bus, device, datapoint, test, node):
        i2c_sample =  term.write('i2cget -y -f %d %d %d %s %d w >> /tmp/%s_%d.txt\n' %(bus, device, datapoint, test, node))

    #output-scraper to slurp results from the output files the i2cgets write to. (devnote: incomplete at time of posting)
    def get_sample_results():
        time.sleep(30)
        term.read_very_eager()
        term.write(b'cat ')
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing I noticed is you don't seem to be checking if your commands are executed. There's no Exception handling to be found.

Second, avoid the use of [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902/1014587).

`telnetlib.open('10.100.100.103')` should be `telnetlib.open(TARGET_IP)`

`time.sleep(3)` should be `time.sleep(SLEEP_INIT)`

Etcetera. Ofcourse, those variables should be declared on the top of your file. Although Python does not support `constant` by default, there's [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688086/1014587) if you're interested.

Comment: the magic numbers are in there for the time being, they're on the to-do list for changing out before this beast i'm creating goes into the wild within the company. consider their presence a temporary state due to this being proof of concept level code. 

i'll make note of the exception handling and start dropping a bit of it into the methods. i've been doing a lot of monitoring with realterm in snoop mode, but you bring up a good point.

Answer (score 3):

#### Global variable `term` vs instance variable `self.term`

Something is off here:

> ```
> class Communications: #logs in to the remote as root.
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.term = telnetlib.open('10.100.100.103')
>         print ('logging in now')
>         term.read_until(b"ogin: ")
> ```

You assign to `self.term`, but then you use `term.read_until` instead of `self.term.read_until`.

Note that `self.term` and `term` are NOT the same thing. `term` is a *free variable*: it's defined in the enclosing code, and it was not passed in as a parameter. `self.term` is an instance variable of the class.

It would seem that in all your methods you really meant to write `self.term` instead of just `term`.

#### Don't take actions in constructors

The constructor (the `__init__` method) logs in without further ado.
It's not usual.
Usually a constructor's job is to create an object,
ready for action but without actually taking any actions.

#### Undefined variables, parameter validation

In this code, what will happen if `node = 3` ?

> ```
> def node_startup(node):
>     if node == 1:
>         node_command = 'node_on 1\n'
>     elif node == 2:
>         node_command = 'node_on 2\n'
>     term.write(node_command)
>     print (b'powering node', node, 'on\n')
> ```

Nothing good. Validate the inputs and handle unexpected values gracefully.

#### Unused variables

The various `get_*_i2c` methods all have this form:

> ```
> def get_something_i2c(bus, device, datapoint, test, node):
>     i2c_sample =  term.write('...')
> ```

They assign to `i2c_sample` and then do nothing else.
As the variable is unused, the code doesn't really make sense.

#### Repetitive code

The `node_startup` and `node_shutdown` have mostly duplicated logic.
It would be better to factor out the duplicated elements to common methods,
for example:

```
def is_valid_node(node):
    return node in (1, 2)

def execute_node_command(node, command, message):
    if not self.is_valid_node(node):
        return
    self.term.write('{} {}\n'.format(command, node))
    print(message, 'node', node)

def node_startup(node):
    self.execute_node_command(node, 'node_on', 'powering on')

def node_shutdown(node):
    self.execute_node_command(node, 'node_off', 'shutting down')
```

Do similarly for the various `get_*_i2c` methods.

#### Naming

`Communications` is too generic. 
And its a plural term, suggesting some sort of a collection.
Something like `NodeManager` would seem more intuitive.

Comment: those repetitive i2c commands were actually one single command instead of various other commands, as they're called in a different script i've been tinkering with the idea of making each command explicit in its name what it does. they output strictly elsewhere to a log file that gets called later. there will be a traffic control signal implemented so that the flow script halts if for some reason they don't work.

Comment: noted on taking the action in the constructor however, i'll make that its own little section. the intention is that when the class is called in the flow, it auto-opens the communications to the remote box and preps for send/receive. i can bake that into the class in places other than the constructor, i believe. 

and the `code`self.term`code` is a really useful note. i had worried about it and turns out i done broke it. that will be updated first thing.